# MonkeyTalk for recording and replaying the user actions; could it work offline?

Tags: energy, consumption, monkeytalk

I want to use MonkeyTalk for recording and replaying the user actions on the mobile device for measuring energy consumption but I don't want the mobile device to be connected the the computer or its WiFi to be on (because it consumes energy) when it is replaying the actions. So does anybody know if the phone has to be connected with a cable or WiFi to the computer when you want to replay the recorded interactions?

I would also appreciate to know if you have any suggestion for using other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Update entire app from SVN to your mac system.You are creating an IOS agent to your app activate for testing.Once running your app then automatically record option is activated in monkey talk automation tool.